# How to use imagemagick in asp.net website?

Tags: .net, asp.net, imagemagick

I am building a new website and it will contain a lot of image manipulations and i found imagemagick which seams very good, but the problem as a .Net developer i can't integrate it in my website. 
Is it possible to use in .Net application/websites?
How to add to reference and which file to add? 
Any good examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Project has an article on this topic: [ImageMagick in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ImageMagick_in_VBNET.aspx). It includes a C++/CLI library that wraps the ImageMagick C++ libraries to make them accessible to .NET applications.